# list of dates without commas

Tags: r, list, date

I have this txt file

```
"","x"
"1","2005-01-31"
"2","2005-03-31"
"3","2005-03-31"
"4","2005-05-31"
"5","2005-05-31"
"6","2005-07-31"
"7","2005-07-31"
"8","2005-08-31"
"9","2005-10-31"
"10","2005-10-31"
```

list of monthly dates. How can I get the same list but without commas, like this one:

```
"x"
"1" "2005-01-31"
"2" "2005-02-28"
"3" "2005-03-31"
"4" "2005-04-29"
"5" "2005-05-31"
"6" "2005-06-30"
"7" "2005-07-29"
"8" "2005-08-31"
"9" "2005-09-30"
"10" "2005-10-31"
```

Thank you!

Comment: choose "," as separator when importing your file

Comment: Thank you Richard! This is my solution :)  So simple, but I didn't try this.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is specify separator while loading file

```
read.csv(file, header = TRUE, **sep = ","**)
```

Comment: it is not about reading in, I already have this as object. I need to write txt file without commas. :/

Comment: If you won't put anything in between, it will be treated as one column. You can add space instead of ","?

Comment: Are you using write.csv()? If yes, it won't work, because csv is comma delimited by definition